# Build last commited SQL Script VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm new to VSTS and I want to know how to always build only the latest committed SQL Script.

*Example:* I committed `example.sql` from my repository, the VSTS Build needs to get only the "example.sql" zip it and publish the artifact to get ready to release.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSTS **build all the existing files/scripts of the current working tree** (specified branch of the repo).

If you want to zip and publish the latest changed files as artifacts, you can  **add a PowerShell task** (for linux and mac, you can use Shell script task instead) for assistant. Detail steps to detect the changed/added as below:

**1.    Use PowerShell task to get changed/added file(s) and copy the file(s) from `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` to another directory** (such as `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\files`). The Powershell script as below:

```
$files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
echo $files
$temp=$files -split ' '
$count=$temp.Length
echo "Total changed $count files"
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\files
For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
{
  $name=$temp[$i]
  echo "this is $name file"
  if (Test-Path "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$name")
    {
      Copy-Item $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$name $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\files
    }
}
```

**2.    Use Archive files task to zip the changed files.** Such as from `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\files` directory to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\pack\$(Build.BuildId).zip`.

[image]

**3.    Use Publish Build Artifacts task to publish the zipped file** from `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\pack` directory.

[image]

Comment: It worked fine, thank you! But when I commit two scripts, in the moment of the release on azure sql database, I'm getting this error: "Found more than one file to deploy with search pattern d:\a\r1\a\**\*.sql. There can be only one." What I need to do?

Comment: No, it's also suitable for the latest commit changed/added more then one files.What's the step did you get error message? And can you show the whole logs here?

Comment: Of course. I'm using Azure SQL Database Deployment. log: https://i.imgur.com/bNiXs0z.png

Also, When I delet a file and add another file in the same commit, it gives me error on the script cuz the file isn't in the repository (it was deleted). "Get-Content : Cannot find path 'D:\a\1\s\tabelarenew.sql' because it does not exist." There's any workaround to solve this?

Comment: For the error screen shot, it's caused deployment package SQL Script should be unique. Since you changes two scrips, and the pattern `**\*.script` matched the two files, that caused the error. You should make sure only one SQL Script is match for a Azure SQL Database Deployment task.

Comment: And I updated the powershell script for dealing with the deleted file(s) in the latest commit.

Comment: Alright, thats what I did: Ignoring the deleted files using -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue and when the commit is one file or more than two files, it will concatenate the content inside of the scripts to combined.sql. That's everything ok with my script? It works like a charm but can be some errors that I can't see and you can. See the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/x9GINB4.png

Comment: In your script, it just trying to split the string `combined.sql` not ignore the file name `combined.sql`. You can have a try for the script which I given in the answer.

Comment: Ok. I used the Add-Content cuz we can't deploy more than one file. So it concatenate two or more files in one and deploy it. The -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue is ignoring the error "xxx.sql doesn't exist" and the script continues. So, everything is ok until now. Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it <3

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can mark it as answer (√ symbol on the left of the answer). And it will help others who have similar questions :)

Comment: I'm not sure the user asked about git specifically. Is there a way to do this with TFVC?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT +1 thanks for the solution. I'm trying to implement your solution with some modification,however blocked with some issues. Could you please check my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232468/how-to-find-the-number-of-new-commitsgit-during-the-tfs-build)