# Create SQL script from commits since last build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfvc

As a DevOps engineer, I want our developers to be able to place SQL scripts in a SQL Server Database Project folder and have the VSTS build agent prepare all scripts committed since the last successful build.

The reason I'm looking for only files since the last successful build is because I only want these scripts to run once. If they are built into a post-deployment script, they will be run every time the database is deployed. Most of these scripts are data changes and not schema changes.

I found this [Build last commited [sic] SQL Script VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47476148/build-last-commited-sql-script-vsts), but the solution applied to a Git repository for latest committed changes instead of a generic solution or TFVC equivalent.

Do I need to look into Visual Studio pre-build events? SQL Server Database Project post-deployment scripts? VSTS build agent task to search for and copy latest files to another location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If they are built into a post-deployment script, they will be run every time the database is deployed.*

The solution to this problem is to make the scripts [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). If data needs to be inserted, check if it's there **before** inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you really want is DBUP, it tracks which scripts have been ran and runs them via a console application.

https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johanclasson.UpdateDatabaseWithDbUp