# How to find the number of new commits(git) during the TFS Build

Tags: git, tfs, tfsbuild

I've followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47504961/7073340) to fetch the files, which are modified in the last commit.

The solutions will be like

```
$files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
echo $files
$temp=$files -split ' '
$count=$temp.Length
echo "Total changed $count files"
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\files
For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
{
  $name=$temp[$i]
  echo "this is $name file"
  if (Test-Path "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$name")
    {
      Copy-Item $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$name $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\files
    }
}
```

With this, I can able to get the modified files from the last commit, but in my case, there may be N- new commit(s).

So I'm seeing a way to achieve this with change the cmd like

2 Commits

`$files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~2 --name-only)`

3 commits

`$files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~3 --name-only)`

like so on.,

However, I couldn't able to find a way to get the no of new commits in the Build definition

### Update 1

My TFS `Get Sources` always check out the corresponding branch with the latest commit id

```
2018-09-08T06:05:35.8623084Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force e88c5a4bf29a539c515ca0e5fea104799426026e
2018-09-08T06:05:36.3681977Z Previous HEAD position was 40ac471... Updated xxxxxxx
```

Which also makes difficult the find the old commit id's as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for [git rev-list](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)

Let's say you perform the following steps:

- You are on master
- You create a hotfix branch: `git checkout -b hotfix_1`
- You modify and commit some files, its hash is `f3de9ae73e1fb06c23506c`
- You modify and commit again. latest hash is `4985ead3183df8388cf8e4`

At this point you're two commits ahead of master, so doing

```
git rev-list HEAD ^master
```

Means: "list those commits that are on my history and not in master's history".

Which in this case prints

```
4985ead3183df8388cf8e4
f3de9ae73e1fb06c23506c
```

(because it makes sense to list them in reverse chronological order).

**However** this method does only make sense when you're comparing branches that haven't diverged. Otherwise, you will only get the number of commits between your HEAD and the last common ancestor, which does not mean the `master` branch hasn't had any new commits since your current HEAD diverged.

Comment: thanks for your response, your solution can work if I use only commits that are on my history and not in master history. Please see my **update 1** My TFS be default checkout the branch with the latest commit Id, so how to get the previous commit id's in such case ?

Comment: So, yout TFS knows the commit sha it will deploy beforehand, right? In that case, you could add a line to your deploy script to capture the hash of the previous deployment (`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`), then run my suggestion between those two. As long as you keep deploying the master branch, which you should, two deploys shouldn't diverge

Comment: Try `git rev-parse HEAD` instead. I'm used to work with branches or tags, so `--abbrev-ref` was not suited for your use case. Pay attention, you pass the latest commit as first parameter, and the previous one (captured with abbrev-ref) as the second one prefixed with `^`. Otherwise, there aren't any commits in the old deploy that the new one doesn't have